# Set of convergent sequences is not a finite dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to study for my finals and there was the following question in one of the exams:

Let $S$ be a set of all convergent sequences $(a_n)$ (the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exists) so $a_i\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$:
$$
S=\{(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)\}
$$
With the operations:
$$
(a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},....)+(b_{1},b_{2},b_{3},....)=(a_{1}+b_{1},a_{2}+b_{2},a_{3}+b_{3},....)
$$
and
$$
c(a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},....)= (ca_{1},ca_{2},ca_{3},....)
$$
Prove that $S$ is not a finite dimensional space.

It also had the following hint: Prove that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there are $n+1$ sequences that are not linear dependent and prove that $S$ is not a finite dimensional space.

I'm struggling over this exercise for almost two hours now. Is it possible to show how it's done?

Answer (score 3):

You are repeatedly  saying 'finite space' instead of 'finite dimensional space'.

Let $e_i$ be the sequence which has $1$ at position $i$ and $0$ elsewhere. Then $e_1,e_2,...,e_n$ are linearly independent for every $n$. Hence the space is infinite dimensional.